# Django admin form error, never saves foreign key even if present

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-cms

I know the title is confusing but let me explain. I am currently implementing a small wiki apphook for a django + django-cms project. I am trying to add sections to the wiki, where the wiki pages can live is specific sections allowing for a bit of structure.

Here is my `model.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from djangocms_text_ckeditor.fields import HTMLField

class WikiPage(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50,primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = HTMLField(blank=True)
    section = models.ForeignKey('WikiSection', related_name='pages', db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class WikiSection(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is my `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import WikiPage, WikiSection
from django import forms
from forms import WikiPageForm, WikiSectionForm

class WikiPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = WikiPageForm

admin.site.register(WikiPage, WikiPageAdmin)

class WikiSectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = WikiSectionForm

admin.site.register(WikiSection, WikiSectionAdmin)
```

ignore the horrible import, I know.

Here is my `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from .models import WikiPage, WikiSection

class WikiPageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WikiPage
        exclude = ['slug']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(WikiPageForm, self).clean()
        print cleaned_data



class WikiSectionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WikiSection
        exclude = ['slug']
```

Now when I try and fill in the field and save the admin form, it always tells me that the section field is required, even though I fill in the field. I also realised that the field is not present in the clean() method. This is what it prints:

```
{'content': u'<p>sdfsdf</p>\r\n', 'name': u'fdfsdf'}
```

[image: error]

**EDIT:**
Also I checked and the data isn't sent in the POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, such a stupid mistake on my part. Since I am excluding the slug field from both models, I needed to override the save method and provide a slug to the object. Here is now my revised `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify
from djangocms_text_ckeditor.fields import HTMLField

class WikiPage(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50,primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = HTMLField(blank=True)
    section = models.ForeignKey('WikiSection', related_name='pages', db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    <!-- ADDED THIS -->
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(WikiPage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    <!-- ADDED THIS -->


class WikiSection(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    <!-- AND THIS -->
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(WikiSection, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    <!-- AND THIS -->
```